# Rails 6 How sign_in and creating sessions works in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

in my project I'm using devise and I want to create custom sign_in. I decided to override create action in SessionsController. Right now my SessionsController looks like that:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    user_signed_in? # -> gives true if correct email and password
    if !current_user.new_one? # -> I have access to current_user
      self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
      set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      yield resource if block_given?
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
    # even if condition is true, user is signed_in
  end
end
```

I'm a little confused because even if I remove whole code from there then user will be signed_in anyway. Can someone explain me why `user_signed_in?` gives me true before `sign_in(resource_name, resource)`? It looks like the user is already logged in? In that case, how can specific users not be allowed to log in? I know there is method `active_for_authentication?`, but I don't want to override it, because I want to allow some users to log in to only part of the application, this method will not allow it and overriding this method will not allow me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding Devise::SessionsController, you still expect some authentication over the params you have parametered (usually email/password).

user_signed_in? method does not the authentication, it's just a helper and it can check if the formerly processed authentication has succeded in the past or not.

The authentication is achieved with use of 'super' at some point of your code.

See :

- https://rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#signed_in%3F-instance_method
  to find an answer to your first question
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-controllers (use of
  super)

Hope it helps